# Is my code a correct implementation of insertion sort?

Tags: java, insertion-sort

This code sorts correctly. Is this an insertion sort?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InsertionSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements: ");
        int count;
        count = sc.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[count];
        System.out.println("Enter elements: ");
        for(int i = 0 ; i<count;i++){
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int j,temp;
        System.out.println("aftr insertion sort :");
        for(int i = 1 ; i<count;i++){
            j=i;
            while(j>0 && a[j-1] > a[j] ){
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j-1];
                a[j-1] = temp;
                j--;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i<count;i++){
            System.out.print(a[i]+"  ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've indented the code properly for you, that makes it slightly easier to read :) You can use this site to do it automatically: http://www.prettyprinter.de/

Comment: Write a test and test it, we are not compilers :)

Comment: If it conforms to the [definition of the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm), then yes...

Comment: It would be clearer, and hence better, and therefore hopefully get you a better grade, if your variable names were meaningful

Comment: Probably not.  But that's just playing the percentages.

Comment: Even i have many implementation of the sorting  but dont know how to find under whichh category it falls. Any clear answer>>

Comment: @Drakosha, yes we are compilers. :-) At least I can read a piece of C code and turn it into something my hardware (i.e. brain) can cope with. There might be bugs… But even if I tell you that this code does compile correctly, that still doesn't verify runtime behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I've focused on the second of the three `for` loops, the one where the actual sorting happens. That loop looks fine to me.